# NextJS project terminates automatically after running 'npm run dev' on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I have recently installed windows 10 and i have also installed NodeJS, react and next. created a project using "npx create-next-app test". after creating when I am going to run the project using "npm run dev" the project terminate/stopping automatic after run. I cannot detect why.

Comment: Do you get any error outputs on your console?

Comment: no console was cleaned. however I have able to find the solution. the problem was with windows firewall, It was blocking the process. Thanks ChatGPT to make life more easier.